# Rust Book: The Twelve Days of Christmas

Tags: performance, rust, lookup

In order to learn Rust I'm going through The Rust Book and did the implemented a program for [the following exercise](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#summary):

> Print the lyrics to the Christmas carol “The Twelve Days of Christmas,” taking advantage of the repetition in the song.

I have decided to use lookup tables for the repeating lines of the song and ordinals because I believe those to be good for performance.

I'd appreciate any comments on my code, especially any suggestions on how to avoid the recurring magic number `12`.

```rust
type Day = u8;

const LYRICS: [&str; 12] = [
    "a partridge in a pear tree",
    "two turtle doves",
    "three French hens",
    "four calling birds",
    "five gold rings",
    "six geese a laying",
    "seven swans a swimming",
    "eight maids a milking",
    "nine ladies dancing",
    "ten lords a leaping",
    "eleven pipers piping",
    "twelve drummers drumming",
];

const ORDINALS: [&str; 12] = [
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "fourth",
        "fifth",
        "sixth",
        "seventh",
        "eigth",
        "ninth",
        "tenth",
        "eleventh",
        "twelfth",
];

fn main() {
    for day in 0..12 {
        if day != 0 {
            println!();
        }

        print_first_line(day);
        print_lyrics(day);
    }
}

fn print_first_line(day: Day) {
    println!(
        "On the {} day of Christmas my true love gave to me",
        ORDINALS[day as usize],
    )
}

fn print_lyrics(day: Day) {
    for line in (0..=day).rev() {
        if line == 0 && day != 0 {
            println!("And {}", LYRICS[line as usize]);
        } else {
            println!("{}", capitalize(LYRICS[line as usize]));
        }
    }
}

fn capitalize(text: &str) -> String {
    let mut chars = text.chars();

    let mut new_text = String::with_capacity(text.len());

    if let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        new_text.extend(c.to_uppercase());
        new_text.extend(chars);
    }

    new_text
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nicely done, I have very little negative to say!
Most of this answer will be an exploration into some more advanced ways of doing what you are doing, overkill for this case, but very useful in larger projects.

- The `day as usize` everywhere is a bit of a distraction. I definitely understand the desire to store a small int when your data is known to be small (i.e. at most 11), but in this case you are only using `Day` as an index, so using `type Day = usize` directly seems like better design.
- However, if you want to be fancy (and/or learn a bit about implementing your own types in Rust), you have an alternative which I will describe below: the basic idea is to implement your own types (use `struct A(B)` instead of `type A = B`), then implement the `Index` trait to index using `Day` directly.
  For a small piece of code like this, it doesn't make a huge difference, but for large projects it's really helpful to avoid accidental mistakes like indexing an array with the wrong variable (i.e. in your case, indexing with some random usize in context instead of a `Day` between 0 and 11).
  If you do that you get a type error, and this also allows you to abstract better: treating `Day` as an opaque type that is used to get the lyrics from your lyrics objects, rather than as an integer with arbitrary functionality. As an added bonus, this also helps avoid the magic number 12 problem that you mention.

  Diving in, we start by defining new types (`struct A(B)`) for `Day` and for a list indexed by `Day`.
  The `#[derive(...)]` is telling Rust that we want Days to be able to be copied, checked for equality, and printed out, copying over that functionality from `u8`.

  ```
  #[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
  struct Day(u8);

  #[derive(Debug)]
  struct DayList<T>([T; 12]);

  const FIRST_DAY: Day = Day(0);
  const LAST_DAY: Day = Day(11);

  const LYRICS: DayList<&str> = DayList([
      ...
  ```

  Then, we implement the ability to index `DayList` objects with `Day`.
  For a variable of type `A` where we defined `struct A(B)`, we use `x.0` to get the underlying `B` data.
  (This explicitness is part of the point of doing this, we make sure to keep `A` variables and `B` variables separate.)

  ```
  impl<T> Index<Day> for DayList<T> {
      type Output = T;
      fn index(&self, day: Day) -> &T {
          self.0.index(day.0 as usize)
      }
  }
  ```

  Finally, we want to be able to iterate over days, something like this utility function seems most useful for your code:

  ```
  fn days_upto(day: Day) -> impl DoubleEndedIterator<Item = Day> {
      (0..=day.0).map(Day)
  }
  ```

  This takes a `Day` and iterates over all days up to and including it. Perhaps this seems like overkill! But we get a lot  of benefit out of it: now we can modify the rest of your code to not have indices at all, and only iterate over Days directly and index `DayList` with `Day`. Type safety! Here's how it looks:

  ```
  fn main() {
      for day in days_upto(LAST_DAY) {
          if day != FIRST_DAY {
              println!();
          }

          print_first_line(day);
          print_lyrics(day);
      }
  }

  fn print_first_line(day: Day) {
      println!(
          "On the {} day of Christmas my true love gave to me",
          ORDINALS[day],
      )
  }

  fn print_lyrics(day: Day) {
      for line in days_upto(day).rev() {
          if line == FIRST_DAY && day != FIRST_DAY {
              println!("And {}", LYRICS[line]);
          } else {
              println!("{}", capitalize(LYRICS[line]));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally: the if block

  ```
  if day != FIRST_DAY {
      println!();
  }
  ```

  can be avoided if you print a title with the lyrics as well, which seems realistic. E.g.:

  ```
  println!("The Twelve Days of Christmas");
  println!("----------------------------");
  for day in days_upto(LAST_DAY) {
      println!();
      print_first_line(day);
      print_lyrics(day);
  }
  ```